# how to remove a system protected folder

Tags: uninstall, directory, delete

how to remove a system protected folder

I tried to install the Ubuntu software repository. But had a power failure after disk 2 of 9 and I was unable to go on to disk 3. As I was going through the readme file that came with the set

**Q: The installer says /usr/repo already exists**

**A: The installer will not install to a directory that already contains data.
   *Examine the files in /usr/repo and delete the files* or copy them
   to another location.**

Upon seeing this I tried to delete the files but it would not let me as they were protected 
but I would rather just remove the folder and start fresh.

in advance I am not trying to install **All** of the software only the Ubuntu repository.

Comment: What in the world are you talking about?  The repository is the set of all software that could possibly ever be installed in Ubuntu.  It is normally hosted on servers.  You don't "install it" and it does not come on disks.

Comment: yes it does come on disks for those that are Internet connection challenged

Comment: Debian does... Ubuntu does not.

Comment: But OSDisk.com does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a termimal and write the following

```
sudo rm -r /usr/repo
```

and you will have your problem solved

Comment: Thank you remember to vote positive if you found it useful. Thank you.